# AngularJS: Error on Factory and routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

In "routeProvider" I have the "objectStats" on resolve, but my controller does not seem to understand it. (I found several problems like on stackoverflow, but no solution solved my error)

My code:

```
var app = angular.module('AppLearning', ['ngRoute','easypiechart']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            resolve: {
                objectStats: function(statsFactory) {
                    return statsFactory.getStatsFollow();
                }
            }
        }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'objectStats', function ($scope, $http, objectStats) {

    $scope.statsUnfollow = objectStats.data;

    $scope.percent = 65;
    $scope.pieOptions = {
        animate:{
            duration:2000,
            enabled:true
        },
        trackColor: '#e5e5e5',
        barColor: '#3da0ea',  
        scaleColor:false,
        lineWidth:5,
        lineCap:'square'
    };

}]);

app.factory('statsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    //Code edited to create a function as when you require service it returns object 
    //by default so you can't return function directly. That's what understand...
    getStatsFollow: function (type) { 
        var q = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/api/stats/follow').success(function (data) {
        q.resolve(function() {
            var settings = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            return settings[type];
        });
      });
      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}]);
```

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: objectStatsProvider <- objectStats
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=objectStatsProvider%20%3C-%20objectStats
>   minErr/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:78:12
>   createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:3546:19
>   getService@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:3673:39
>   createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:3551:28
>   getService@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:3673:39
>   invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:3700:1
>   instantiate@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:3721:23
>   $ControllerProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:6772:18
>   nodeLinkFn/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:6185:34
>   forEach@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:310:11
>   nodeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:6172:11
>   compositeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:5636:15
>   compositeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:5639:13
>   compositeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:5639:13
>   publicLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:5541:30
>   bootstrap/doBootstrap/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:1304:11
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:11955:16
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:12055:18
>   bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:1302:9
>   invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:3710:14
>   bootstrap/doBootstrap@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:1300:1
>   bootstrap@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:1314:1
>   angularInit@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:1263:5
>   @https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js:20555:5
>   b.Callbacks/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:7852
>   b.Callbacks/p.fireWith@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:8658
>   .ready@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:3264
>   H@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:693

Comment: Looks fine so far... could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: My guess is that you have `ng-controller="AppCtrl"` somewhere in your view. You shouldn't: the controller is instantiated by the router. Post your view.